# Binding IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,BaseDto>> type object in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my WPF application(mvvm) in my ViewModel I have something like this:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,SomeClass>> FeildSet = Feilds
         .GroupBy(e => e.Label.Substring(0, 1));
```

How will I bind this FeildSet Object in my view inside a DataTemplate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What the Definition of your DataTemplate?

Answer (score 1):

1. Since `FeildSet` is collection (at least it is an enumerable) I would suggest to use a control that is built-in to handle collections of objects (i.e. any control which base class is [`ItemsControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Now, each item in `FeildSet` is also a collection of `SomeClass` grouped by `String`, so I suggest to use a control that is able to show a header and some content (i.e. any control which base class is [`HeaderedContentControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx#inheritanceContinued)).
3. The content of each group would again be shown by an [`ItemsControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).

This gives you the following canvas:

```
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FeildSet}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <HeaderedContentControl
                Header="{Binding Path=Key}">
                <ItemsControl
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!-- template for SomeClass here -->
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </HeaderedContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```